# Vagrant/VirtualBox shared folders without vboxsf

Tags: linux, vagrant, virtualbox, mmap

I'm working on a project that uses Vagrant (with a Linux guest) for the build environment. The build process relies on `mmap()` to build certain application-specific binaries. Unfortunately, `vboxsf`, VirtualBox's mechanism for sharing a directory with the host, [seems to have some (7 year old) problems with `mmap`](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/819#comment:61).

I can work around it by working in the guest's private storage then copying files back to the shared directory, but that's ugly and slow.

For logistical reasons, I cannot use another Vagrant provider than VirtualBox, nor can I modify the project to avoid using `mmap()`.

Does anyone know if there are other means to share the directory with VirtualBox, and whether Vagrant could be configured to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vagrant can use different strategies for syncing folders. Currently, in addtion to `vboxsf`, you can choose between:

- **NFS** (on Linux and OS X hosts)
- **SMB** (on Windows hosts)
- **Rsync** (one-way only)

You can find more info by reading the [official Vagrant docs](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/index.html).

Comment: Ah.. thanks! I've been poring over VirtualBox docs and the Vagrantfile "Provider" docs. Didn't occur to me the synced folder mechanisms would be Provider-independent. Cheers!